# Azure Functions warm-up trigger beyond Minimum Instances

Tags: azure-functions

Does the warm up trigger work for the instances beyond the pre warmed instances up to the max instances? Or in other words: using the warm up trigger can I be sure that all instances up to the max number (and so beyond the pre warmed ones) are warmed up before getting traffic?

Answer (score 1):

> **In the Premium plan, you can have your app [pre-warmed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=(ir__emcwv29mt9kftn6qkk0sohzx0v2xngwqx2rd6eih00)(7593)(1243925)(je6NUbpObpQ-VW831Pg7Yi.Bwr49OyXpeQ)()&irclickid=_emcwv29mt9kftn6qkk0sohzx0v2xngwqx2rd6eih00#pre-warmed-instances) on a specified number of instances, up to your minimum plan size**. Pre-warmed instances also let you pre-scale an app before high load. As the app scales out, it first scales into the pre-warmed instances. Additional instances continue to buffer out and warm immediately in preparation for the next scale operation. By having a buffer of pre-warmed instances, you can effectively avoid cold start latencies.

**You can configure the number of pre-warmed instances** in the Azure portal by selected your Function App, going to the Platform Features tab, and selecting the Scale Out options. In the function app edit window, pre-warmed instances is specific to that app, but the **minimum and maximum instances apply to your entire plan**.

So if you want to make sure that all instances up to the max number, you can set pre-warmed instances to the max. You can set it using Azure cli.

```
az resource update -g <resource_group> -n <function_app_name>/config/web --set properties.preWarmedInstanceCount=<desired_prewarmed_count> --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites
```

Comment: Thanks Joey what I'm still not sure about is:
if I set Min Instances to 1, Max instances to 10 and pre-warmed to 1, at any given time do I have at least two instances running for me? The main one and the pre-warmed one? 
When it scales out to 2 instances, do I have 3 of them running for me? Two receiving traffic and 1 pre warmed? And so on?
As far as I have understood you pay for both the up and running instances and the pre-warmed ones, correct?